# Updating XML column with the new XML using parameterized stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is something new for me to try using XML column in SQL server 2008 database. I have seen few posts related to this, but I am able to find it difficult.

Let me put my question in a simplest form.

1. I have a database table dbo.cXML that has the columns EmailID(nVarchar(128)), ClientID(int) and cycleXML(XML).
2. My middleware component implements complex business logic and spit out the XML after logic processing.
3. Now I have a requirement that need the following:

a) A stored procedure with parameters in place to perform a check on above table to see if there is already an XML for a given EmailID and Client ID. If a record exists, use Update query to update entire XML otherwise simply insert the XML.

b) A stored procedure whould be able to send back the complete XML to my middleware component on request.

Can someone please help me understand the pseudo code. Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Yagya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure what you mean by requirement 3b but does this help you???

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.cXML WHERE EmailID = @YourEmailID AND ClientID = @YourClientID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.cXML
    SET cycleXML = @YourXML
    WHERE EmailID = @YourEmailID AND ClientID = @YourClientID
END
ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.cXML (EmailID, ClientID, cycleXML)
    SELECT @YourEmailID, @YourClientID, @YourXML
END
```